# Get the fastest goroutine

Tags: go

How to get only the result of the fastest goroutine. For example let's we have this function.

```
func Add(num int)int{
   return num+5
}
```

And we have this function.

```
func compute(){
  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
     go Add(i)
  }
}
```

I want to get the result of the goroutine that finishes first.

Comment: Use a channel to deliver the results. Receive once from the results channel. To avoid blocking, use buffered channel or non-blocking send. You may also want to signal the rest of the goroutines that their work is no longer needed so they may terminate early. E.g. with `context.Context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `buffered channel` to get first result of many grouting execution

```
func Test(t *testing.T) {
    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            go func(c chan<- int, i int) {
                res := Add(i)
                c <- res
            }(ch, i)
        }
    }()
    res := <-ch // blocking here, before get first result
    //close(ch) - writing to close channel produce a panic
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/TijYjyyM1VX)</kbd>

<strike>It hasn't memory leak when leave a `channel` open and never close it. When the `channel` is no longer used, it will be **garbage collected**.</strike>

Comment: "it will be garbage collected" - are you sure about that? You still have a reference to the channel in the blocked go routines - see [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/bfuwmhbZHYw/PNnKk4hGytgJ), [article](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/11/goroutine-leaks-the-forgotten-sender.html) and [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19702#issuecomment-289825220). If you make the buffer bigger (`make(chan int, 4)`) then the go routines can exit (allowing the garbage collector to free the channel).